# requestLocationUpdates 2nd paramater is in km or m

Tags: java, android, android-location, android-gps

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, distance, locationListener);
here
time is in milliseconds or second?
distance is in km or m?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The android API is very well documented, you can find your answer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper)).

[image]

This should answer your question, but I greatly recommand you to read the android developers documentation for any further question about it, you'll find everything you need.